# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter must not be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

With Springboot update from 2.7.2 to 3.2.0 ,now Filter class started throwing exception

> Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException:
> Unable to start embedded Tomcat   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:501)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
> ... 11 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter must not be null   at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172)  at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.getDescription(AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.java:223)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean.onStartup(RegistrationBean.java:47)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:241)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4850)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:488)    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
> ... 16 common frames omitted

The code which look like throwing exception

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements  WebMvcConfigurer  {

    @Value("${system.debug.enabled:false}")
    private boolean debugEnabled;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(httpHeaderInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/log/**").allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "PUT", "PATCH", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept")
                .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptor httpHeaderInterceptor() {
        return (HandlerInterceptor) new HttpHeaderInterceptor();
    }
     
    private FilterRegistrationBean newFilterRegistrationBean(Filter filter, int order) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(order);
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean stopWatchFilter() {
        Filter filter = debugEnabled ? new StopWatchFilter() : new NoopFilter();
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = newFilterRegistrationBean(filter, 1);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean gzipFilter() {
        GZipRequestFilter gzipRequestFilter = new GZipRequestFilter();
        return newFilterRegistrationBean(gzipRequestFilter, 2);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registerOpenSessionInViewFilterBean() {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter openEntityManagerInViewFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
        return newFilterRegistrationBean(openEntityManagerInViewFilter, 1);
    }
}
```

As per my understanding this throwing exception

```
 @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean gzipFilter() {
        GZipRequestFilter gzipRequestFilter = new GZipRequestFilter();
        return newFilterRegistrationBean(gzipRequestFilter, 2);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registerOpenSessionInViewFilterBean() {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter openEntityManagerInViewFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
        return newFilterRegistrationBean(openEntityManagerInViewFilter, 1);
    }
```

But the place class is initializing but still its telling `NULL`. After removing this code its starting server.

Comment: The `newFilterRegistrationBean` doesn't do anything with the passed in `Filter`. I wonder why they are in there at all, as those can be enabled by configuration alone ( the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` is registered by default, and the gzip one can be enabled by a configuration setting).

Comment: is that a typo on `newFilterRegistrationBean`? ie `new FilterRegistrationBean`

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you give any example how its done in latest release.

Comment: A `FilterRegistration` with no relation to a `Filter` doesn't make sense. You need to call `setFilter`. But as said you shouldn't need those filters as those are already addd.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the filter parameter to FilterRegistrationBean constructor as below

```
   private FilterRegistrationBean newFilterRegistrationBean(Filter filter, int order) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(order);
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```